# Dynamic Spannable columns in RecyclerView (Not fixed spans)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

This is what I want to implement(Shown in picture below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4GaO.png)), where base is recycler View.
I found [this link](https://github.com/riontech-xten/StaggeredTextGridView) but it is using BaseAdapter.I tried to implement change it to make it useful for my work but I am ending up with errors,
Any suggestion might be helpful.

Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Comment: Have you found some solution for this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I tackled it by creating a custom view which is having a relative layout as its base and i am adding these tags dynamically...i tried but ws not having time to put much effort on it..so instead i created a custom view. if that helps i can give you link to that repo.

Comment: Thank you, but finally I found this https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/FlowLayout , it's perfect for me